# How can I change zoom based on markers in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Is there any way to dynamically change the zoom of the map based on markers ?

I'm using this code to get leaflet.js map

```js
if (document.getElementById('map')) {
  let map;
  //set up the Leaflet.js map
  map = L.map('map', { center: [{{ latitude }}, {{ longitude }}], zoom: 12 });

  // tiles etc
  L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'kalvo'
  }).addTo(map); { %
    for element in data %
  }
  var customIcon = {
    iconUrl: "{{ element.icon }}",

    iconSize: [20, 30]
  };
  var iconOptions = {
    icon: L.icon(customIcon)
  };
  var marker = new L.Marker([{
    {
      element['latitude']
    }
  }, {
    {
      element['longitude']
    }
  }], iconOptions).addTo(map);
  var popup = L.popup()
    .setContent($("#{{ element.identifiant }}").html());
  marker.bindPopup(popup, {
    maxWidth: 600
  }); { % endfor %
  }
}
```

instead of using 12 as default value I'd like to have this number based on markers that I have to show them all because now it shows only few onesand I'd like to show all marks

Comment: Please explain in text what you mean instead of just showing code and hoping folks figure out what you're talking about. The statement "based on markers" doesn't tell folks anything, so explain what you mean with that: describe what you need to have happen based on a description of what happens in/on your leaflet instance.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have lot of markers and when I add the zoom this way : map = L.map('map', { center: [{{ latitude }}, {{ longitude }}], zoom: 12 }); It shows only few ones. I'd like to show them.

Comment: Don't add details in comments, add them [to your post](/help/how-to-ask). Especially since the answer you accepted has nothing to do with setting a zoom level based on markers, which means it can't possible be the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flyto function to set zoom level and animatation as well.
Here zoom is set to 10.

```
 map.flyTo([lat[1], lng[0]], 10, {
        animate: true,
        duration: 2 // in seconds
      });
```

Reference [here](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-flyto)